# My RabbitMQ subscription code doesn't work

Tags: java, python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm trying to get notifications from a `RabbitMQ` residing on a server. I've been told to use this code, which should print progress notifications. But when running the code and submitting a job to the queue, I'm not seeing anything. The code doesn't print anything:

```
import pika

rabbitMqHost = 'host'
rabbitMqUser = 'user'
rabbitMqPass = 'password'
exchangeName = 'ProgressNotification'


credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(rabbitMqUser, rabbitMqPass)

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(rabbitMqHost, 5672, '/', credentials))
channel = connection.channel()

# channel.exchange_delete(exchange=exchangeName)
# exit(3)

channel.exchange_declare(exchange=exchangeName, exchange_type='fanout')

result = channel.queue_declare()
queue_name = result.method.queue

channel.queue_bind(exchange=exchangeName,
                   queue=queue_name)


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print("> %r" % (body,))

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue=queue_name,
                      no_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

Sorry, I'm very new to `RabbitMQ`. But is there another step or something missing?! Why it doesn't show anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script works fine. I pushed a message to a queue called simple_queue using the exchange `ProgressNotification` and your script printed.

> b'Hello World!'

I used this script, based on my own RabbitMQ library, but you can just use [this](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/master/examples/publish.py) pika example as a reference.

```
from amqpstorm import Connection
from amqpstorm import Message

with Connection('127.0.0.1', 'guest', 'guest') as connection:
    with connection.channel() as channel:
        # Declare the Queue, 'simple_queue'.
        channel.queue.declare('simple_queue')

        # Create the message.
        message = Message.create(channel, 'Hello World!')

        # Publish the message to a queue called, 'simple_queue'.
        message.publish('simple_queue', exchange='ProgressNotification')
```

In Java you would need to publish your message like this.

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

public class Send {

    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "simple_queue";
    private final static String EXCHANGE_NAME = "ProgressNotification";

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        try (Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
             Channel channel = connection.createChannel()) {
            channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
            String message = "Hello World!";
            channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You code looks concise! So I can not use it without having your library?

Comment: You can not but I can give you a similar example with pika I a day or two (traveling at the moment)

Comment: If my code already works, no worries. I wonder why it just doesn't print anything.

Comment: No need to share your code. I will need to use Java for this. If you can share Java equivalent, would be great!

Comment: I added a Java version as well @TinaJ.